# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column .JPA Entity Issue?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, jakarta-ee, runtime-error

I have this [error](https://pastebin.com/uuJeGmPB) when I trying to send a GET request to my Spring Boot Application and I don't know what I missed out!

I have this [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n7hu.jpg) and I created the **JPA Entities** and the relationships in Eclipse, with STS (Spring Tool Suite) installed for my Spring Boot Project, accordingly.

**The Entities created are:**

**Categoria.java**

```
package gnammy.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * The persistent class for the categoria database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "categoria")
@NamedQuery(name = "Categoria.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Categoria c")
@NamedQuery(name = "Categoria.findByIdRistorante", query = "SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Categoria c INNER JOIN c.portate p INNER JOIN p.ristoranti r WHERE r.idRistorante = :idRistorante")
public class Categoria implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idCategoria", nullable = false, unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int idCategoria;

    private String descrizione;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Portata
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoria")
    private List<Portata> portate;

    public Categoria() {
    }

    public Categoria(String descrizione) {
        super();
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public Categoria(int idCategoria, String descrizione) {
        super();
        this.idCategoria = idCategoria;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public int getIdCategoria() {
        return idCategoria;
    }

    public void setIdCategoria(int idCategoria) {
        this.idCategoria = idCategoria;
    }

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return this.descrizione;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public List<Portata> getPortate() {
        return this.portate;
    }

    public void setPortate(List<Portata> portatas) {
        this.portate = portatas;
    }

    public Portata addPortata(Portata portata) {
        getPortate().add(portata);
        portata.setCategoria(this);

        return portata;
    }

    public Portata removePortata(Portata portata) {
        getPortate().remove(portata);
        portata.setCategoria(null);

        return portata;
    }
}
```

**Ordine.java**

```
package gnammy.entities;    

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;    

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;    

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;    

/**
 * The persistent class for the ordine database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "ordine")
@NamedQuery(name = "Ordine.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM Ordine o")
public class Ordine implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idOrdine", nullable = false, unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int idOrdine;    

    @Column(name = "idRistorante", nullable = false, unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int idRistorante;    

    private String indirizzoConsegna;    

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date orarioConsegna;    

    private String tipoPagamento;    

    private String note;    

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date dataOrdine;    

    private float totale;    

    private String cartaDiCredito;    

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to Portata
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ordine_portata", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "IdOrdine", referencedColumnName = "IdOrdine") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "IdPortata", referencedColumnName = "IdPortata") })
    private List<Portata> portate;    

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Ristorante
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "IdRistorante", referencedColumnName = "IdRistorante")
    private Ristorante ristorante;    

    public Ordine() {
    }    

    public Ordine(int idRistorante, String indirizzoConsegna, Date orarioConsegna, String tipoPagamento, String note,
            Date dataOrdine, float totale, String cartaDiCredito) {
        super();
        this.idRistorante = idRistorante;
        this.indirizzoConsegna = indirizzoConsegna;
        this.orarioConsegna = orarioConsegna;
        this.tipoPagamento = tipoPagamento;
        this.note = note;
        this.dataOrdine = dataOrdine;
        this.totale = totale;
        this.cartaDiCredito = cartaDiCredito;
    }    

    public Ordine(int idOrdine, int idRistorante, String indirizzoConsegna, Date orarioConsegna, String tipoPagamento,
            String note, Date dataOrdine, float totale, String cartaDiCredito) {
        super();
        this.idOrdine = idOrdine;
        this.idRistorante = idRistorante;
        this.indirizzoConsegna = indirizzoConsegna;
        this.orarioConsegna = orarioConsegna;
        this.tipoPagamento = tipoPagamento;
        this.note = note;
        this.dataOrdine = dataOrdine;
        this.totale = totale;
        this.cartaDiCredito = cartaDiCredito;
    }    

    public int getIdOrdine() {
        return idOrdine;
    }    

    public void setIdOrdine(int idOrdine) {
        this.idOrdine = idOrdine;
    }    

    public int getIdRistorante() {
        return idRistorante;
    }    

    public void setIdRistorante(int idRistorante) {
        this.idRistorante = idRistorante;
    }    

    public String getCartaDiCredito() {
        return this.cartaDiCredito;
    }    

    public void setCartaDiCredito(String cartaDiCredito) {
        this.cartaDiCredito = cartaDiCredito;
    }    

    public Date getDataOrdine() {
        return this.dataOrdine;
    }    

    public void setDataOrdine(Date dataOrdine) {
        this.dataOrdine = dataOrdine;
    }    

    public String getIndirizzoConsegna() {
        return this.indirizzoConsegna;
    }    

    public void setIndirizzoConsegna(String indirizzoConsegna) {
        this.indirizzoConsegna = indirizzoConsegna;
    }    

    public String getNote() {
        return this.note;
    }    

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }    

    public Date getOrarioConsegna() {
        return this.orarioConsegna;
    }    

    public void setOrarioConsegna(Date orarioConsegna) {
        this.orarioConsegna = orarioConsegna;
    }    

    public String getTipoPagamento() {
        return this.tipoPagamento;
    }    

    public void setTipoPagamento(String tipoPagamento) {
        this.tipoPagamento = tipoPagamento;
    }    

    public float getTotale() {
        return this.totale;
    }    

    public void setTotale(float totale) {
        this.totale = totale;
    }    

    public List<Portata> getPortate() {
        return this.portate;
    }    

    public void setPortate(List<Portata> portate) {
        this.portate = portate;
    }    

    public Ristorante getRistorante() {
        return this.ristorante;
    }    

    public void setRistorante(Ristorante ristorante) {
        this.ristorante = ristorante;
    }
}
```

**Portata.java**

```
package gnammy.entities;    

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;    

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;    

/**
 * The persistent class for the portata database table.
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "portata")
@NamedQuery(name = "Portata.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Portata p")
@NamedQuery(name = "Portata.findByIdRistorante", query = "SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Portata p INNER JOIN p.ristoranti r WHERE r.idRistorante = :idRistorante")
public class Portata implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idPortata", nullable = false, unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int idPortata;    

    @Column(name = "idCategoria", nullable = false, unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int idCategoria;    

    private String nome;    

    private String descrizione;    

    private float prezzo;    

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to Ordine
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "portate")
    private List<Ordine> ordini;    

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Categoria
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "IdCategoria", referencedColumnName = "IdCategoria")
    private Categoria categoria;    

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to Ristorante
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "portate")
    private List<Ristorante> ristoranti;    

    public Portata() {
    }    

    public Portata(int idCategoria, String nome, String descrizione, float prezzo) {
        super();
        this.idCategoria = idCategoria;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.prezzo = prezzo;
    }    

    public Portata(int idPortata, int idCategoria, String nome, String descrizione, float prezzo) {
        super();
        this.idPortata = idPortata;
        this.idCategoria = idCategoria;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.prezzo = prezzo;
    }    

    public int getIdPortata() {
        return idPortata;
    }    

    public void setIdPortata(int idPortata) {
        this.idPortata = idPortata;
    }    

    public int getIdCategoria() {
        return idCategoria;
    }    

    public void setIdCategoria(int idCategoria) {
        this.idCategoria = idCategoria;
    }    

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return this.descrizione;
    }    

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }    

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }    

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }    

    public float getPrezzo() {
        return this.prezzo;
    }    

    public void setPrezzo(float prezzo) {
        this.prezzo = prezzo;
    }    

    public List<Ordine> getOrdini() {
        return this.ordini;
    }    

    public void setOrdini(List<Ordine> ordini) {
        this.ordini = ordini;
    }    

    public Categoria getCategoria() {
        return this.categoria;
    }    

    public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }    

    public List<Ristorante> getRistoranti() {
        return this.ristoranti;
    }    

    public void setRistoranti(List<Ristorante> ristoranti) {
        this.ristoranti = ristoranti;
    }
}
```

**Ristorante.java**

```
package gnammy.entities;    

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;    

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;    

/**
 * The persistent class for the ristorante database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "ristorante")
@NamedQuery(name = "Ristorante.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Ristorante r")
@NamedQuery(name = "Ristorante.findByIdTipoCucina", query = "SELECT DISTINCT r FROM Ristorante r INNER JOIN r.tipiCucina tc WHERE tc.idTipoCucina = :idTipoCucina")
public class Ristorante implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idRistorante", nullable = false, unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int idRistorante;    

    private String nome;    

    private String indirizzo;    

    private String numeroTelefonico;    

    private String orario;    

    private float costoDiConsegna;    

    private float ordineMinimo;    

    private String linkSito;    

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Ordine
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ristorante")
    private List<Ordine> ordini;    

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to Portata
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ristorante_portata", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "IdRistorante", referencedColumnName = "IdRistorante") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "IdPortata", referencedColumnName = "IdPortata") })
    private List<Portata> portate;    

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to TipoCucina
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ristorante_tipo_cucina", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "IdRistorante", referencedColumnName = "IdRistorante") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "IdTipoCucina", referencedColumnName = "IdTipoCucina") })
    private List<TipoCucina> tipiCucina;    

    public Ristorante() {
    }    

    public Ristorante(String nome, String indirizzo, String numeroTelefonico, String orario, float costoDiConsegna,
            float ordineMinimo, String linkSito) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
        this.numeroTelefonico = numeroTelefonico;
        this.orario = orario;
        this.costoDiConsegna = costoDiConsegna;
        this.ordineMinimo = ordineMinimo;
        this.linkSito = linkSito;
    }    

    public Ristorante(int idRistorante, String nome, String indirizzo, String numeroTelefonico, String orario,
            float costoDiConsegna, float ordineMinimo, String linkSito) {
        super();
        this.idRistorante = idRistorante;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
        this.numeroTelefonico = numeroTelefonico;
        this.orario = orario;
        this.costoDiConsegna = costoDiConsegna;
        this.ordineMinimo = ordineMinimo;
        this.linkSito = linkSito;
    }    

    public int getIdRistorante() {
        return idRistorante;
    }    

    public void setIdRistorante(int idRistorante) {
        this.idRistorante = idRistorante;
    }    

    public float getCostoDiConsegna() {
        return this.costoDiConsegna;
    }    

    public void setCostoDiConsegna(float costoDiConsegna) {
        this.costoDiConsegna = costoDiConsegna;
    }    

    public String getIndirizzo() {
        return this.indirizzo;
    }    

    public void setIndirizzo(String indirizzo) {
        this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
    }    

    public String getLinkSito() {
        return this.linkSito;
    }    

    public void setLinkSito(String linkSito) {
        this.linkSito = linkSito;
    }    

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }    

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }    

    public String getNumeroTelefonico() {
        return this.numeroTelefonico;
    }    

    public void setNumeroTelefonico(String numeroTelefonico) {
        this.numeroTelefonico = numeroTelefonico;
    }    

    public String getOrario() {
        return this.orario;
    }    

    public void setOrario(String orario) {
        this.orario = orario;
    }    

    public float getOrdineMinimo() {
        return this.ordineMinimo;
    }    

    public void setOrdineMinimo(float ordineMinimo) {
        this.ordineMinimo = ordineMinimo;
    }    

    public List<Ordine> getOrdini() {
        return this.ordini;
    }    

    public void setOrdini(List<Ordine> ordini) {
        this.ordini = ordini;
    }    

    public Ordine addOrdine(Ordine ordine) {
        getOrdini().add(ordine);
        ordine.setRistorante(this);    

        return ordine;
    }    

    public Ordine removeOrdine(Ordine ordine) {
        getOrdini().remove(ordine);
        ordine.setRistorante(null);    

        return ordine;
    }    

    public List<Portata> getPortate() {
        return this.portate;
    }    

    public void setPortate(List<Portata> portate) {
        this.portate = portate;
    }    

    public List<TipoCucina> getTipiCucina() {
        return this.tipiCucina;
    }    

    public void setTipiCucina(List<TipoCucina> tipiCucina) {
        this.tipiCucina = tipiCucina;
    }
}
```

**TipoCucina.java**

```
package gnammy.entities;    

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;    

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;    

/**
 * The persistent class for the tipo_cucina database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "tipo_cucina")
@NamedQuery(name = "TipoCucina.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TipoCucina t")
public class TipoCucina implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idTipoCucina", nullable = false, unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int idTipoCucina;    

    private String descrizione;    

    private String immagine;    

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to Ristorante
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tipiCucina")
    private List<Ristorante> ristoranti;    

    public TipoCucina() {
    }    

    public TipoCucina(String descrizione, String immagine) {
        super();
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.immagine = immagine;
    }    

    public TipoCucina(int idTipoCucina, String descrizione, String immagine) {
        super();
        this.idTipoCucina = idTipoCucina;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.immagine = immagine;
    }    

    public int getIdTipoCucina() {
        return idTipoCucina;
    }    

    public void setIdTipoCucina(int idTipoCucina) {
        this.idTipoCucina = idTipoCucina;
    }    

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return this.descrizione;
    }    

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }    

    public String getImmagine() {
        return this.immagine;
    }    

    public void setImmagine(String immagine) {
        this.immagine = immagine;
    }    

    public List<Ristorante> getRistorantes() {
        return this.ristoranti;
    }    

    public void setRistorantes(List<Ristorante> ristorantes) {
        this.ristoranti = ristorantes;
    }
}
```

What I missed out???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the stack trace it is evidentthat the spring jpa is converting your column name incorrectly.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ristorante0_.id_ristorante' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:970) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1020) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2173) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1936) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2695) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2678) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2512) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1538) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1561) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1529) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at gnammy.repositories.RistoranteRepositoryImpl.listaRistoranti(RistoranteRepositoryImpl.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
```

In your stack trace while trying to execute the method *listaRistoranti(RistoranteRepositoryImpl.java:54)* on the Entity class `Ristorante` , jpa converts the column name given as  `@Column(name = "idRistorante")` to the camel case `id_ristorante` ,while in the database the column name is `idRistorante` itself, which is causing the issue.

From the *Configure Hibernate Naming Strategy* section of the [Spring data access howto guides](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html):

> **Hibernate** uses two different **naming strategies** to map names from the object model to the corresponding database names. The fully qualified class name of the **physical and the implicit strategy implementations** can be configured by setting the `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy and spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy properties`, respectively. Alternatively, if **ImplicitNamingStrategy** or **PhysicalNamingStrategy** beans are available in the application context, Hibernate will be automatically configured to use them.
>
> By default, Spring Boot configures the physical naming strategy with
>   SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy. This implementation provides the same
>   table structure as Hibernate 4: all dots are replaced by underscores
>   and camel casing is replaced by underscores as well. By default, all
>   table names are generated in lower case, but it is possible to
>   override that flag if your schema requires it.

Try using the following property in the `application.properties` or `application.yml` whichever you are using, so that spring jpa does not convert your column name and use it as it is specified in your Entity.

**Application.yml**

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

Comment: yes, adding 'spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl' to my application.properties file made the trick. Thanks.