# Spring Boot - Use underscored table and column names for custom data source

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to configure two data sources for a Spring Boot project. Here is my configuration file for primary data source.

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:application-local.properties"})
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManager",
        basePackages = {"portal.api.repository"}
)
public class PrimaryDbConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"portal.api.model"});

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("app.datasource.spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                env.getProperty("app.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("app.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("app.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("app.datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager userTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                primaryEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

The tables are generated but their names and column names are in camel case. However I would like to have the underscore names which spring boot has by default. For example `ApiKey` entity would be changed to table name `api_key`.

How do I configure Spring Boot to use the underscored naming strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use @Column(name = "api_key") in your instance variable for your domain model it'll work.

e.g.

```
    @Column(name = "api_key")
    private String apiKey;
```

Comment: That could work but I am working on an existing code base with a lot of entities so adding that annotation for every entity would be tedious

Comment: I don't believe there is another way. You'd have to overwrite hibernates default mapping mechanism. Perhaps have a look at the hibernate source code and see if you can change that, but you'd probably be quicker changing your project to use column.

Answer (score 0):

Reference from [Official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html)

> By default, Spring Boot configures the physical naming strategy with
>   SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy. This implementation provides the same
>   table structure as Hibernate 4: all dots are replaced by underscores
>   and camel casing is replaced by underscores as well.

You can set the following property in `application.yml` to tell springboot which naming strategy to use:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

Similar post for reference:
[java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column .JPA Entity Issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102676/java-sql-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-unknown-column-jpa-entity-issue/56105735#56105735)

Comment: The given application.yml properties did not convert the entity names to underscored table names. The table names are same as entity names

Comment: Try setting this property in application.yml and for physical naming stratergy provide the spring implementation

Comment: I tried setting physical-strategy to SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy and it still gives me camel case names

Comment: If you are using springboot actuator , try hitting the /beans endpoint to view which bean is getting created in springboot. It will give you a better idea about the existing configurations.